# HighChart pie tooltip fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is pie chart `http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/`, but when I enable tooltip with mouse it moves depending of cursor. How can I fix tooltip, but not like `options.tooltip.positioner = (function () {return { x: 20, y: 100 }});`, because tooltip must be near the pie piece. Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look for `followPointer: Boolean` option for highchart
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.followPointer

Comment: I can not understand why in doc is written that they are false by default? Ofcource I tried to use it, but didn't tried to both of followPointer and followTouchMove to false. Finally, everything works.Thanks.